# toggle on px-accordion fails and throws error in firefox browser

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion, accordionpane

The below is the basic px-accordion tag which I am using.

```
<px-accordion class="start-expanded" header-value="Report">
    ....
</px>
```

Trying to toggle it by default on selecting the respective tab. Below is the snippet for toggle functionality.

```
MD.ui.panels
  .getActivePanel()
  .el.find('px-accordion.start-expanded')
  .each(function() {
    $(this)[0].toggle();
  });
};
```

Unfortunately, the toggle function is throwing an error in firefox browser saying "TypeError: $(...).toggle is not a function".

note: the same code is working fine in chrome. I believe in firefox, the toggle() is called before the px-accordion element loads which throws the error.

Comment: Any change if you use latest version of jquery?Also is your code inside a document.ready statement?

Comment: Yeah... I am using the latest version of Jquery. I tried to put it in document.ready. But, no luck. The element itself is failing to load.